# Setting a DIV to 100% height

Tags: css

I'm setting a DIV to 100% height as shown in this example: http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/full-height-updated.html, but the problem is that the `<body>` tag background color does not work if the page has scrolling.

Has anyone achieved 100% height div tags successfully, or can you tell me what this tutorial is missing?

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
* html #content {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2F404A;
    color: #505050;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

The dark area is the  tag, whereas you can see the content is extending beyond the body tag.

Screenshot: http://img833.imageshack.us/i/screenshotxh.png/

Comment: Can you show your code to explain what exactly you mean? Obviously (as the page shows) 100% height is possible.

Comment: I was able to modify the site you gave (with Chrome's inspection tool) and made sure scrolling took place, changed the background color, and it all works as expected. You must not be mimicking the site correctly.

Comment: Do you understand that when setting the Div height to be 100%, that you are asking the Div to calculate this relative to the height of it's Containing Block... and not necessarily from the height of the Viewport?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2F404A;
    color: #505050;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
* html #content {
    height: 100%;
}
```